# How to pass erb page elements to javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I have a force directed d3.js graph. On it there are nodes. When a node is clicked, a partial shows details about that node. The node represents a user and the details are taken from one table in the database- a User table. I have got this to work.

three of the columns contain integers and I would like to display these on a further d3.js graph within the partial.

The partial receives an object called @user which contains all of the data from the User table for that user.

I would like to pass the @user.scorecolumn1, @userscorecolumn2 and @user.scorecolumn3 to a d3.js barchart.

#### So far on the page I have the list of elements from @user based on the selected user

```
<ul>
    <li>Name: <%= @user.name %></li>
    <li>Email: <%= @user.email %></li>
    <li>Id: <%= @user.id %></li>
    <li>Score1 <%= @user.scorecolumn1 %></li>
<li>Score2 <%= @user.scorecolumn2 %></li>
<li>Score3 <%= @user.scorecolumn3 %></li>
</ul>
```

#### And then the d3.js javascript that I want to use, also using @user

```
var margin ={top:20, right:30, bottom:30, left:40},
    width=960-margin.left - margin.right, 
    height=500-margin.top-margin.bottom;

// scale to ordinal because x axis is not numerical
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

//scale to numerical value by height
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var chart = d3.select("#chart")  
              .append("svg")  //append svg element inside #chart
              .attr("width", width+(2*margin.left)+margin.right)    //set width
              .attr("height", height+margin.top+margin.bottom);  //set height
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(x)
              .orient("bottom");  //orient bottom because x-axis will appear below the bars

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(y)
              .orient("left");
```

#### How do I put the values above, namely

```
<%= @user.scorecolumn1 %>
<%= @user.scorecolumn2 %>
<%= @user.scorecolumn3 %>
```

#### into var data below so that it looks like:

```
var data =[
  {letter: "Score1", frequency: <%= @user.scorecolumn1 %>},
  {letter: "Score2", frequency: <%= @user.scorecolumn2 %>},
  {letter: "Score3", frequency: <%= @user.scorecolumn3 %>}
];
```

#### Rest of code

```
  x.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.letter}));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.frequency})]);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                    .data(data)
                  .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
                      return "translate("+x(d.letter)+", 0)";
                    });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
        return y(d.frequency); 
      })
      .attr("x", function(d,i){
        return x.rangeBand()+(margin.left/4);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return height - y(d.frequency); 
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());  //set width base on range on ordinal data

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", x.rangeBand()+margin.left )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency) -10; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });

  chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+ height+")")        
        .call(xAxis);

  chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+",0)")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Frequency");


function type(d) {
    d.letter = +d.letter; // coerce to number
    return d;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please name the files for code snippets above

Comment: Also add the d3 js initialization statement (start point for rendering the chart)

Comment: Its all in the same page. The d3.js declaration is also on the same page

Comment: I havent included all the code for the sake of brevity. I think the relevant bits are there though

Answer (score 2):

There is a really simple solution, just add the javascript for the data in your view. Make sure the javascript code for the chart is in the assets, and render the data for the charts in the view in javascript directly.

Like so:

```
<script>
  var data=<%= [{letter: "Score1", frequency: @user.scorecolumn1}, ...].to_json %>;  
</script>
```

and then you can just use that variable in your d3 script.

Answer (score 0):

You can set score column values in to hidden input field, and then get  those values with JS.

First set score value below your user fields:

```
<ul>
<li>Name: <%= @user.name %></li>
<li>Email: <%= @user.email %></li>
<li>Id: <%= @user.id %></li>
<li>Score1 <%= @user.scorecolumn1 %></li>
<li>Score2 <%= @user.scorecolumn2 %></li>
<li>Score3 <%= @user.scorecolumn3 %></li>
</ul>

<div style="display:none">
  <input id='scorecolumn1' name="scorecolumn1" value= '<%= @user.scorecolumn1 %>' >
  <input id='scorecolumn2' name="scorecolumn1" value= '<%= @user.scorecolumn1 %>' >
  <input id='scorecolumn3' name="scorecolumn1" value= '<%= @user.scorecolumn1 %>' >
</div>
```

Then get those values from JS code:

```
var data =[
{letter: "Score1", frequency: $("#scorecolumn1").value },
{letter: "Score2", frequency: $("#scorecolumn2").value },
{letter: "Score3", frequency: $("#scorecolumn3").value }
];
```